# Remove Inline Css Rules injected through Woocommerce into Head Section (woocommerce-inline-inline-css)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Woocommerce injects the following inline css rule into the head section of my theme. Any idea how to remove it through my child themes functions.php?

```
    <style id='woocommerce-inline-inline-css' type='text/css'>.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }</style>
```

If im not missing anything the following code block in the woocommerce plugins file  `...woocommerce-includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` is responsible for it.

```
    // Placeholder style.
    wp_register_style( 'woocommerce-inline', false ); // phpcs:ignore
    wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce-inline' );

    if ( true === wc_string_to_bool( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_highlight_required_fields', 'yes' ) ) ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', '.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }' );
    } else {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', '.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: hidden; }' );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following action removes

`<style id='woocommerce-inline-inline-css' type='text/css'>.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }</style>`

from the head section. Code goes into your functions.php file of your child or parent theme.

**Input from O. Jones in the comments:** Or, consider using the Code Snippets plugin to hold these small tweaks to a site. If you edit functions.php you may (a) have it overwritten by an update, (b) possibly lose track of where you put your tweaks.

```
        // Remove the following from head section - see source code
        // <style id='woocommerce-inline-inline-css' type='text/css'>.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }</style>
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_woo_inline_css_head_ac',11);
            function remove_woo_inline_css_head_ac() {
            wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce-inline' );
        }
```

Comment: Or, consider using the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin to hold these small tweaks to a site. If you edit functions.php you may (a) have it overwritten by an update, (b) possibly lose track of where you put your tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **//** before function to comment that line

This is the code correctly:

```
// Placeholder style.
wp_register_style( 'woocommerce-inline', false ); // phpcs:ignore
wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce-inline' );

if ( true === wc_string_to_bool( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_highlight_required_fields', 'yes' ) ) ) {
   //wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', '.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }' );
} else {
   //wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', '.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: hidden; }' );
}
```

Comment: I'm not in favor to edit core woocommerce files. There must be way to override or deactivate it through a filter or action hook i guess.